Excel VBA: Search Folder and Subfolder given input and display hyperlink to PDF (partially complete)
So, I have a bunch of part numbers and am trying to automate the creation of hyperlinks to PDFs on one of the drives. Of course this drive has main and sub folders to search through for this. Below is the file check code to make sure the pdf is there and properly formatted however, i am having trouble getting it to make another column with the hyperlinks or even just the path address, as we can make this into a hyperlink with normal functions pretty easily.
[Edit] I cannot post pictures yet however, the input is from Column B starting at row 2.
I have gotten it to display the part number again by deleting some of the array writing however, i still cannot get just the path address to show up. In addition, if anyone could help me get the debug.print to save to text file working that would be awesome. It gives me a syntax error when trying to define the debug as a string. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i am new to VBA but, have some C+ experience to go off of.
Sub checkFiles()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "P:\K-XXXX"
    Const FileExt As String = "PDF" ' Not case-sensitive i.e. 'DXF = dxf'
    Const fFound As String = "Yes"
    Const fNotFound As String = "Error"
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "B2"
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "C2"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    
    Dim rng As Range      ' (Source and Destination) Data Range
    Dim Data As Variant   ' (Source and Destination) Data Array
    Dim fData() As String ' File Data Array
    Dim mData As Variant  ' Match Data Array
    Dim n As Long         ' File Data and (Match) Data Array Elements Counter
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Set rng = defineColumnRange(defineRange(wb.Worksheets(srcName), srcFirst))
    Data = getColumn(rng)
    'Debug.Print "Source Data:" & vbLf & Join(Application.Transpose(Data), vbLf)
    
    ' Write file paths to File Data Array.
    fData = getFilePaths(FolderPath, "*." & FileExt)
    Debug.Print "File Data - File Paths:" & vbLf & Join(fData, vbLf)
    
        Dim s As String
        Dim y As Integer

        y = FreeFile()
        Open "U:\Product Tracking\test.txt" For Output As #y

        s = Debug.Print "File Data - File Paths:" & vbLf & Join(fData, vbLf)
        Print #y, s ' write to file

        Close #y
    
    ' Replace file paths with file names without file extension.
    For n = LBound(fData) To UBound(fData)
        fData(n) = FileFromPath(fData(n), True) ' 'True' means no extension.
    Next n
    Debug.Print "File Data - File Names:" & vbLf & Join(fData, vbLf)
    
'        Dim s As String
'        Dim y As Integer
'
'        y = FreeFile()
'        Open "U:\Product Tracking\test.txt" For Output As #y
'
'        s = Debug.Print "File Data - File Names:" & vbLf & Join(fData, vbLf)
'        Debug.Print s ' write to immediate
'        Print #y, s ' write to file
'
'        Close #y

    ' Write 'matches' to Match Data Array.
    mData = Application.Match(Data, fData, 0)
    'Debug.Print "Match Data:"
    'For n = 1 To UBound(mData)
    '    Debug.Print mData(n, 1)
    'Next
    
    ' Overwrite values in Data Array with 'matching results'.
    For n = 1 To UBound(Data) ' or 'UBound(mData)'
        If IsNumeric(mData(n, 1)) Then
            Data(n, 1) = fFound
        Else
            Data(n, 1) = fNotFound
        End If
    Next n
    'Debug.Print "Destination Data:" & vbLf _
        & Join(Application.Transpose(Data), vbLf)
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Range.
    With defineRange(wb.Worksheets(dstName), dstFirst)
        Dim RowOffset As Long: RowOffset = .Row - rng.Row
        Dim ColumnOffset As Long: ColumnOffset = .Column - rng.Column
        Set rng = .Worksheet.Range(rng.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset).Address)
    End With
    rng.Value = Data
    
End Sub

Function defineRange( _
    ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal RangeAddress As String) _
As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set defineRange = ws.Range(RangeAddress)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function defineColumnRange( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCell
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
            Set rng = rng.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set defineColumnRange = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function

Function getColumn( _
    rng As Range) _
As Variant
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If InStr(rng.Address, ":") > 0 Then
            getColumn = rng.Value
        Else
            Dim Data As Variant
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
            getColumn = Data
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function getFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "") _
As Variant
    Dim ExecString As String
    ExecString = "cmd /c Dir """ & FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator _
        & FilePattern & """ /b/s"
    getFilePaths = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
        .Exec(ExecString).StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".") ' 'vbCrLf' is a must.
End Function

Function FileFromPath( _
    ByVal FilePath As String, _
    Optional ByVal NoExtension As Boolean = False) _
As String
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Right(FilePath, _
        Len(FilePath) - InStrRev(FilePath, "\"))
    If NoExtension Then
        FileName = Left(FileName, InStrRev(FileName, ".") - 1)
    End If
    FileFromPath = FileName
End Function





s = "File Data - File Paths:" & vbLf & Join(fData, vbLf): Debug.Print s

Untested but this should be close:
Sub checkFiles()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "P:\K-XXXX"
    Const FileExt As String = "PDF" ' Not case-sensitive i.e. 'DXF = dxf'
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "B2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, c As Range, m, pn As String
    Dim rngPN As Range, fData() As String, n As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Set c = ws.Range(srcFirst)
    Set rngPN = ws.Range(c, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, c.Column).End(xlUp)) 'part numbers
    
    fData = getFilePaths(FolderPath, "*." & FileExt) 'find all files
    'loop over found files, try to match base filename to `rngPN`
    '  and insert link if found
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = LBound(fData) To UBound(fData)
        pn = FileFromPath(fData(n), True)    'no extension.
        m = Application.Match(pn, rngPN, 0)  'match?
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=rngPN.Cells(m).Offset(0, 1), _
                              Address:=fData(n), _
                              TextToDisplay:="Link"
        End If
    Next n
End Sub

Function getFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "") _
As Variant
    Dim ExecString As String
    ExecString = "cmd /c Dir """ & FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator _
        & FilePattern & """ /b/s"
    getFilePaths = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
        .Exec(ExecString).StdOut.ReadAll, vbcrlf), ".") ' 'vbCrLf' is a must.
End Function

Function FileFromPath(ByVal filePath As String, _
           Optional ByVal NoExtension As Boolean = False) As String
    Static fso As Object
    'FSO has handy methods for this type of work....
    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FileFromPath = fso.GetFileName(filePath)
    If NoExtension Then FileFromPath = fso.GetBaseName(FileFromPath)
End Function

